# Is there a way I can make shortcut for "2>&1 &"

Tags: shell-script

Every time I have to type `script.sh > log.txt 2>&1 &` I feel tired. I've tried using `alias bg21=2>&1 &` but it doesn't work properly.

For example, if I do:

```bash
echo 5 > test.log bg21
```

I would see in test.log file has:

```bash
5 bg21
```

Comment: Instead of an alias or wrapper which will only make things more obtuse, consider using some key binding, eg. `bind '"\C-_": "2>&1 &"'` in bash (change the C-_ = C-7, C-&, C-/ if you're already used to use them for "undo")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a function:

```
function bkg { 2>&1 "$@" & }
```

And then use:

```
bkg script.sh arg1 arg2 ... >log.txt
```

Comment: @mosvy It does for me...

Comment: Yes it does, sorry.

Comment: Thanks! it works. However I have new problem in doing this, that the background process will now show as  ```bash [1] "$@" 2>&1``` which I cannot tell any useful information what's running there. Not sure if we can get avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to redirect both stdout and stderr to a file, you can simply write

```bsh
echo 5 &> test.log &
```

This is the shortest way I know to accomplish what you want here.

Comment: that's a BASH-ONLY deprecated feature, which in all the other shells will be parsed differently, namely as `echo 5 &` followed by `>test.log &` (the `test.log` file will be truncated, and nothing will be written to it).

Comment: It works on my bash environment well. It looks cleaner and avoided the problem of hidden process descriptions in background that @xenoid 's solution introduced.